# overleaf Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: tables

Could anyone please advise why I am getting the above error message. Apologies not able to figure out the issue. The & is correct. Many Thanks

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{12}{|c|}{Display Format} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Senescent}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Young}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Senescent}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Young}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Senescent}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Young}&
\hline
0.6482 & 0.5074 & 
0.6482 & 0.5074 & 
0.6482 & 0.5074 & 
0.6482 & 0.5074 & 
0.6482 & 0.5074 & 
0.6482 & 0.5074 &
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Number of respondents for treatment}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Replace `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Young}& \hline` with `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Young}\\ \hline` and `0.5074 & \hline` with `0.5074 \\ \hline` and your code should compile. `&` jumps to the next cell in the same table row. Since you want to add a `\hline`, remove the `&` and end the table row with a `\\ ` instead.

Comment: Many Thanks! That worked perfectly.